# Reading calendar folder in a date range using JACOB

Tags: calendar, outlook, jacob

hi guys is it possible on JACOB on reading only CALENDAR folder with a date range and let me get the subject. If yes please give a sample code for reference. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This code has two filters

1) first only by date range - start and end date

2) filter by subject = "test"

If you need only date, you can omit second filter.

[How to: Filter Recurring Appointments and Search for a String in the Subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/bb611267.aspx)

```
Dispatch namespace = outlokAx.getProperty("Session").toDispatch();
Dispatch calendarFolder = Dispatch.call(namespace, "GetDefaultFolder", new Integer(9)).toDispatch();
Dispatch calItems = Dispatch.get(calendarFolder, "items").toDispatch();

  String customFilter = "@SQL=\"urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart\" > '" +  DateUtility.dateToUtcString(startDate) + "' and  \"urn:schemas:calendar:dtend\" = '" +  DateUtility.dateToUtcString(endDate) + "'" ;
String customFindFilter = "@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\" like '" + "test" + "'" ;

Dispatch restrictedItems = Dispatch.call(calItems, "Restrict", new Variant(customFilter)).toDispatch(); //Works only with dates
Dispatch.call(calItems, "Sort", "[Start]");
Dispatch.put(restrictedItems, "IncludeRecurrences", "False");

int numberOfMatchingItems = 0;

Dispatch lastitemFound = null;
if (restrictedItems != null && restrictedItems.m_pDispatch > 0) {

  Dispatch findItem = Dispatch.call(restrictedItems, "Find", customFindFilter).toDispatch(); // Find Works with other attributes
  while (findItem != null && findItem.m_pDispatch > 0) {
    numberOfMatchingItems++;
    lastitemFound = findItem;
    findItem = Dispatch.call(restrictedItems, "FindNext").toDispatch();
    Variant start = Dispatch.get(findItem, "Start");
    Variant end = Dispatch.get(findItem, "End");
    Variant subject = Dispatch.get(findItem, "Subject");
    System.out.println("# Outlook event fetched: " + subject + " start: '" + start + "' end '" + end + "'");
  }
}
```